# get xml data from jquery

Tags: jquery

Is this even doable? I have an xml file formatted as so;

```
<CoordinateData>
 <Country name="Australia">  
  <Marker>  
      <LocationName>Port of Coff&#39;s Harbour</LocationName>
      <Longitude>153.0900</Longitude>
      <Latitude>-30.1800</Latitude>
      </Marker>
  <Marker>      
      <LocationName>Port of Sydney</LocationName>
      <Longitude>151.1750</Longitude>
      <Latitude>-33.4500</Latitude>     
  </Marker>
  <Marker>      
      <LocationName>Port of Melbourne</LocationName>
      <Longitude>144.9450</Longitude>
      <Latitude>-37.8370</Latitude>     
  </Marker>
  </Country>
  <Country name="USA">
  <Marker>
    <LocationName>Natchez_MS</LocationName>
    <Longitude>91.4030</Longitude>
    <Latitude>31.5603</Latitude>
  </Marker>
  <Marker>
    <LocationName>Paducah_KY</LocationName>
    <Longitude>88.6010</Longitude>
    <Latitude>37.0833</Latitude>
  </Marker>   
</Country>
```

The file is shortened for brevity but you get the picture. I want to retrieve the data for a specific country based on a dropdown selection. I want to retrieve all the lat and long data for that countries markers. To determine the charts center i want to put all the latitudes in an array and average them for the chart center latitude and do the same for longitude. I can retrieve the data via .get but im not familiar with how to parse and average the retrieved data in jquery. The goal is to have one avg latitude and one avg longitude to use as the maps center coordinates.

I can't seem to even GET the xml data. The file is in the folder OtherDataFiles which is a folder in the root of my website. The following code doesn't even show the alert.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "OtherDataFiles/CoordinateData.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('Marker').each(function() {
                    if (id === "") {
                        id = $(this).attr('name');
                    } else {
                        id = id + "," + $(this).attr('name');
                    }


                });
            }
        });
        alert(id);
    });
```

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: What development environment are you using? The general idea is to populate a database, set up a web service, the query that service using AJAX calls within the client page. jQuery is very useful for this sort of thing. Let us know what your database situation is like.

Comment: .parseXML then .find('country[name="' + country_name + '"] Marker').each(...)

Comment: lots of tutorials on web how to parse xml using jquery.... yes is doable and not difficult

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I had a minor emergency. I updated the post to include the jquery ajax code. I cant even retrieve any data to an alert. Im assuming im not accessing the file properly

Comment: check you console for any errors

Comment: was getting an error on id.tostring in the alert. I changed it to just alert(id); and the alert is showing undefined, which i assume means its not finding anything

Comment: Am i accessing the file in my directory structure properly?